# How should I retrieve a BTC asset from NaoBTC?

Tags: dex

In experimenting with the stellar DEX I've acquired 0.0001 BTC from NaoBTC. [NaoBTC withdraw page](https://naobtc.com/#/howto/withdraw) states:

> If your wallet or tool supports it, send your BTC asset to a address like this: 1BTCAddressYouProvided*naobtc.com We will send out bitcoin to the address you provided.

So I logged into StellarTerm clicked `account-->send` and in the destination field I filled `0.0001BTC<MY_WALLET_ADDRESS>*naobtc.com` and got the response `Unable to resolve address`.

If I fill in `<MY_WALLET_ADDRESS>*naobtc.com` (i.e. without the BTC amount) it seems to be able to resolve the address, although I'm not sure how the transfer could then take place without me requesting a specific amount.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right,
you need to put it as `<MY_WALLET_ADDRESS>*naobtc.com`

for amount there is a separate field in every wallet.

But for amount like yours I don't recommend you doing this. Withdrawal fee is <s>0.0005 BTC as far as I know</s> *(UPDATE: looks like withdrawal fee is 0.0002 BTC)* , so you just gonna lose your coins. The only way is to exchange it back to XLM and work with that.

Comment: Wanting to test the process and not caring about fees I sent 0.0001 BTC to `<MY_WALLET_ADDRESS>*naobtc.com` and while my account on stellarterm now shows I have 0 BTC (as opposed to 0.0001 before), I can't see any withdraws corresponding the transaction time in NaoBTC's withdraw query page nor do I see BTC added to my BTC wallet. It's been 80 minutes since I made the transaction, I'll wait some more to see if something changes.

Comment: as I said, it's because fee exceeds your withdrawal, it has been consumed completely. You won't see any transaction on Bitcoin network.

Comment: Right. I was expecting it the transaction to be rejected if the fee exceeds it, but reading up a bit I realize it doesn't work that way. In any case, I retried to send 0.0006 BTC and this one got through (with a 0.0002 fee).

Comment: ok, means my info about fee amount is outdated